# Failure/Error: expected: 1 time with any arguement, recieved: 0 times with any arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have a below spec, where i am `mocking` my user model and `stubbing` its method.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do 

  let(:username) {"test@test.com"}
  let(:password) {"123"}
  let(:code) {"0"}

  context "when signing in" do
    let(:expected_results) { {token:"123"}.to_json }

    it "should sign in" do 
      expect(User).to receive(:login).with({email: username, password: password, code: code})
        .and_return(expected_results)
    end

  end    
end
```

I get the below error, when i try to run my test case.

```
Failure/Error: expect(User).to receive(:login).with({email: username, password: password, code: code})
       (<User (class)>).login({:email=>"test@test.com", :password=>"123", :code=>"0"})
           expected: 1 time with arguments: ({:email=>"test@test.com", :password=>"123", :code=>"0"})
           received: 0 times
```

Comment: So, to be clear, you have a User method called `login` ?  And there's no controller action defined.  At what point do you expect the User.login to be called?  When you do `sessions#create` ?  There's no call to that controller method... or any controller method.

Comment: Maybe you can include your sessions controller code, and the User model, in your question?  If this is a model unit test, though, then mocking isn't appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 9):

You are misunderstanding what `expect` is.

`expect(x).to receive(:y)` is stubbing out the `y` method on the `x`.

ie, it is papering over that method.

A way of describing this would be that you are making an "expectation that method `y` will be called on `x` when you actually run your code"

Right now, you spec doesn't call any actual code... it just sets up the expectation... then stops.

If you are *testing* the method `login` then you need to not stub it out with an expectation, but actually call it for real.

eg `User.login(email: username, password: password, code: code)`

You currently don't actually have a test at all. Just a stub that you set up, and then never use.

Comment: It may be worth checking where you are calling the `expect` method. Here's a mistake that gave us a headache:

```rb
#  Error! expected: 1 time with any arguments. received: 0 times with any arguments 
expect(@notification_service).to receive(:send_notification)
post :create, :params => { :hub_id => 123, :notification => notification_data }
```

When it should have been:

```rb
# ✅
post :create, :params => { :hub_id => 123, :notification => notification_data }
expect(@notification_service).to receive(:send_notification)
```

Answer (score 1):

As @taryn-east mentioned, you aren't actually testing the `User.login` method.

You likely want something like this:

```rb
it "should sign in" do 
  expect(User).to receive(:login).with({email: username, password: password, code: code})
    .and_return(expected_results)
  User.login(email: username, password: password, code: code)
end
```

### Still Having Issues?

It may be worth checking where you are calling the `expect` method. Here's a mistake that gave me a headache:

```rb
# ❌ Failure/Error: expect(@notification_service).to receive(:send_notification)  
# (ClassDouble(NotificationService) (anonymous)).send_notification(*(any args))
#   expected: 1 time with any arguments
#   received: 0 times with any arguments
expect(@notification_service).to receive(:send_notification)
post :create, :params => { :hub_id => 123, :notification => notification_data }
```

When it should have been:

```rb
# ✅
post :create, :params => { :hub_id => 123, :notification => notification_data }
expect(@notification_service).to receive(:send_notification)
```